# Proper way to read variable from one thread and write from another?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create a application with 2 threads. Where in the main thread I have a variable (Int32) that I would only read from the main thread.

Now I have another thread runs in loop as long as the program is running, this thread creates a "heartbeat" that when reaches some point, I'd like to update the variable said above. The variable is only written from this heartbeat thread and never from any other thread.

To keep the precision (QueryPerformanceCounter level), I'd like to avoid any possible blocking on the heartbeat thread.

Here's a simplified version:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Interval = 0;

        static void Heartbeat()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < 100) {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine($"Heartbeat : {counter}");
                if (counter % 10 == 0) {
                    Interval = counter;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread heartbeat = new Thread(Heartbeat);
            heartbeat.Start();

            while (Interval < 100) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Interval  : {Interval}");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It runs, but I wonder if my practice is correct. If not, how should I improve it?

To summary:

1. `Interval` is **only** read by main thread.
2. `Interval` is **only** modified by `Heartbeat` thread.
3. I'd like to avoid any blocking on `Heartbeat` thread, preferably not blocking main thread as well.

Edit:

I just realized I was reading `Interval` in `Heartbeat()` with the `while` block, so I changed it from `while (Interval < 100)` to `while (counter < 100)`

Edit2:

1. The code above is a very simplified version, the real code is a bit mess and I don't think posting all the API part would help this question.
2. I **don't** need the main thread to do something as soon as the Interval is updated. It's more likely to be read only once per loop, like this:

```
int interval;
while (Interval < 100 /* I could use some other condition not invoving Interval */ ) {
    interval = Interval;
    // all usage of "Interval" from this point would use the value read in interval
    Console.WriteLine($"Interval  : {interval}");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

3. As long as the value read in main thread is a legit value (calculated in `Heartbeat` thread) not something else, I'm fine with it. For example, if the value is updated at exactly the same time when I read it for this loop, it's ok to get either the old value or the new value, as long as it's not some irreverent value out of no where. (In case it reads the old value, it would read the new one on the next loop, right?)

Comment: This feels like an X-Y problem. What are you trying to actually do with the two threads in the end?

Comment: @AKX I'm trying to write a simple game, the main thread would be my game loop, and I'd like to have a second thread to keep track on when VBlank happens (with ```D3DKMTWaitForVerticalBlankEvent()```, it blocks so I have to use another thread) so I can calculate an accurate refresh rate. My monitor says it's 60Hz but in reality it's about 59.920Hz, tested with [UFO TEST](https://www.testufo.com/refreshrate)

Comment: An uncontested [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) costs around 20 nanoseconds of CPU time. Is this too much of a delay for your heartbeat thread?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Please read my updated question, can I get away without it for my use case? What's the benefit/drawback of using ```lock```? (The loop in main thread would run as many times as the FPS, e.g. if the game runs at 120FPS it would loop 120 times a second, each loop would read ```Interval``` once.)

Comment: [Interlocked Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Locking is the safe way of communication between threads, because each thread obtains exclusive access to the shared data. Benifit: easy to write a correct multithreaded program. Drawbacks: 1) bad performance if heavy contested and 2) possibility of deadlocks. For a novice to multithreading it is the go-to solution. Lock-free multithreading is, [as Jeff Atwood once said](https://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/), for tough guys who grow hair on their chest by losing hair on their heads. You'd better stay away from it until you know very well what you are doing.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov After reading that, am I correct to assume that read / write to Int32 is already "Interlocked"? (and Int64 is also when running on 64-bit mode)

Answer (score 0):

Even without blocking and very short work your timer thread will suffer from slippage, since it's work time is not 0. I think you will be better off with a timer.

Please see [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) has running in a multithreaded setup built in.

> The server-based System.Timers.Timer class is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to handle the raised Elapsed event, resulting in more accuracy than Windows timers in raising the event on time.

and

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

Finally:

> Tip
>
> Be aware that .NET includes four classes named Timer, each of which offers different functionality:
>
> - **System.Timers.Timer** (this topic): fires an event at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
> - **System.Threading.Timer**: executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
> - **System.Windows.Forms.Timer** (.NET Framework only): a Windows Forms component that fires an event at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment.
> - **System.Web.UI.Timer** (.NET Framework only): an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.

Comment: The code I posted above is a very simplified version (the full code is a mess...) I **don't** need main thread to do something as soon as the ```Interval``` is updated. I'll edit the question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect. You can use `lock` or `volatile` to fix it. It's about memory model.

> The purpose of a memory model is to enable thread communication. When one thread writes values to memory and another thread reads from memory, the memory model dictates what values the reading thread might see.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice

Optimization may change your code `while (Interval < 100)` to `while (true)`, the compiler or runtime or processor is allowed to do it but it does not have to do it. So your code may works for your environment but it's still incorrect.

You can check ECMA-334 8.10 Execution order to know the detail rule.

> Execution of a C# program proceeds such that the side effects of each executing thread are preserved at
> critical execution points. A side effect is defined as a read or write of a volatile field, a write to a nonvolatile variable, a write to an external resource, and the throwing of an exception. The critical execution
> points at which the order of these side effects shall be preserved are references to volatile fields (§15.5.4),
> lock statements (§13.13), and thread creation and termination. The execution environment is free to
> change the order of execution of a C# program, subject to the following constraints:

- Data dependence is preserved within a thread of execution. That is, the value of each variable is
  computed as if all statements in the thread were executed in original program order.
- Initialization ordering rules are preserved (§15.5.5, §15.5.6).
- The ordering of side effects is preserved with respect to volatile reads and writes (§15.5.4).
  Additionally, the execution environment need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that
  that expression’s value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused
  by calling a method or accessing a volatile field). When program execution is interrupted by an
  asynchronous event (such as an exception thrown by another thread), it is not guaranteed that the
  observable side effects are visible in the original program order.